# How to control the inner join query in sequelize using node.js?

Tags: node.js, join, sequelize.js, inner-join

Days model:

```
workoutId: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
},
traineeId: {
  type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
  primaryKey: true
},
dayNumber: {
  type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
  primaryKey: true
},
status: {
  type: Sequelize.INTEGER
},
```

WorkoutsExercises model:

```
workout_id: {
  type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
  primaryKey: true
},
exercise_name: {
  type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
  primaryKey: true
},
coach_id: {
  type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
  primaryKey: true
}
```

I just want to make an inner join between the two tables to return all exercises in each day, I use the following

```
const Days = require('../models/days');
const WorkoutsExercises = require('../models/workoutsExercises');

Days.findAll({
  include: [{
    model: WorkoutsExercises,
      required: true
   }]        
})
```

And this function returns the following query:

```
SELECT
  `day`.`workoutId`,
  `day`.`dayNumber`,
  `day`.`status`,
  `day`.`traineeId`,
  
  `workoutsExercises`.`workout_id` AS `workoutsExercises.workout_id`, 
  `workoutsExercises`.`exercise_name` AS `workoutsExercises.exercise_name`, 
  `workoutsExercises`.`coach_id` AS `workoutsExercises.coach_id`

FROM `days` AS `day`

INNER JOIN `workoutsExercises` AS `workoutsExercises` 

ON `day`.`dayNumber` = `workoutsExercises`.`workout_id`;
```

how can I change the on condition from (`day`.`dayNumber`) to (`day`.`workoutId`)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The relation should be as the following

```
WorkoutExercises.hasMany(Day, {foreignKey: 'workout_id'})
Day.belongsTo(WorkoutExercises, {foreignKey: 'workout_id', targetKey: 'workout_id'})
```

the target key is what changes the ON clause, and we will use the same query:

```
Days.findAll({
  include: [{
    model: WorkoutsExercises,
    required: true
  }]        
})
```

which gives:

```
SELECT

  `day`.`dayNumber`,
  `day`.`dayDate`,
  `day`.`status`,
  `day`.`traineeId`, 
  `day`.`workoutId`, 

  `workoutsExercises`.`exercise_name` AS `workoutsExercises.exercise_name`,
  `workoutsExercises`.`workout_id` AS `workoutsExercises.workout_id`,
  `workoutsExercises`.`coach_id` AS `workoutsExercises.coach_id`
 
 FROM `days` AS `day`
 
 INNER JOIN `workoutsExercises` AS `workoutsExercises`
 
 ON `day`.`workout_id` = `workoutsExercises`.`workout_id`;
```

Answer (score 1):

1. If you have several relations between two models you can create several associations:

   ```
   User.hasMany(Task);
   Task.belongsTo(User);

   User.hasMany(Task, {as: "secondAssociation", foreignKey, sourceKey});
   Task.belongsTo(User, {as: "secondAssociation", foreignKey, targetKey});
   ```

   And you can run this queries with different ON clause, determined by foreignKey (and sourceKey/targetKey) value, that you provide to create associations:

   ```
   User.findAll({
     include: [{
       model: Task
     }]

   User.findAll({
     include: [{
       model: Task,
       as: "secondAssociation"
     }]
   })
   ```
2. If you want change ON clause for given query, you can use `include[].on` option of [Model.findAll](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/model.js~Model.html#static-method-findAll) method.

   ```
   User.findAll({
     include: [{
       model: Task,
       on: {} //Use Sequelize.Op.col for reference on other column
     }]
   ```